# Function's If/else statement not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get a "Login Success/Fail" text appear when we click on the login button if the user and the password are equal.

The problem I am having is that no matter what the user and password we write it always display the "success" message instead of the fail one.

I am using the `.get` to get the input of the user and saving on a variable.

Heres my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

label_name = Label(root, text="Username", fg="black")
label_password = Label(root, text="Password", fg="black")
input_name = Entry(root)
name = input_name.get()
input_password = Entry(root, show="*")
password = input_password.get()

label_name.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
label_password.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)

input_name.grid(row=0, column=1)
input_password.grid(row=1, column=1)

checkbox = Checkbutton(root, text="Remember me")
checkbox.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)

login_button = Button(root, text="Login")
login_button.grid(row=1, column=2)


login_success = Label(root, text="Welcome", fg="black")
login_fail = Label(root, text="login fail", fg="black")


def login(event):
    if name == password:
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.grid_forget()
        login_true = Label(root, text="Welcome", fg="black")
        login_true.grid()
    elif name != password:
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.grid_forget()
        login_false = Label(root, text="login fail", fg="black")
        login_false.grid()


login_button.bind("<Button-1>", login)

root.mainloop()
```

EDIT:
I also used the "command" attribute but it had the same result:

```
def login():
    name = input_name.get()
    password = input_password.get()
    if name == password:
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.grid_forget()
        login_true = Label(root, text="Welcome", fg="black")
        login_true.grid()
    elif name != password:
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.grid_forget()
        login_false = Label(root, text="login fail", fg="black")
        login_false.grid()


login_button = Button(root, text="Login", command=login)
login_button.grid(row=1, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

EDIT2:
Fixed by adding an new condition

```
def login():

    if input_name.get() == "" or input_password.get() == "":
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.grid_forget()
        login_false = Label(root, text="login fail", fg="black")
        login_false.grid()
    elif input_name.get() == input_password.get():
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.grid_forget()
        login_true = Label(root, text="Welcome", fg="black")
        login_true.grid()
    elif input_name.get() != input_password.get():
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.grid_forget()
        login_false = Label(root, text="login fail", fg="black")
        login_false.grid()
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't believe you. That edit works for me and one other user. What are you entering into the two text boxes? If they're not different, it won't fail.

Comment: @EthanField Yes i was mistaken. FIx it and its working now, thanks for the help.

Comment: I have suggested an edit that removes "[SOLVED]" as this is disallowed on Stack Exchange, [see here for why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/372286).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it always returns true is because you have declared `name` and `password` in two local namespaces. One in the main body of your code and one within the function `login()`. `name` and `password` within the `login()` function both equal `None` because they never have an assigned value. Meaning that they are always equal and will always return `True`.

Change the function to the below:

```
def login():
    if input_name.get() == input_password.get():
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.grid_forget()
        login_true = Label(root, text="Welcome", fg="black")
        login_true.grid()
    elif input_name.get() != input_password.get():
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.grid_forget()
        login_false = Label(root, text="login fail", fg="black")
        login_false.grid()
```

---

Using `.bind()` on a `Button` widget for `<Button-1>` tends to be a terrible idea. `Button` widgets have a built in attribute called `command` which can be used to called get a callback when clicked:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def login():
    print("Login triggered")

login_button = Button(root, text="Login", command=login)
login_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

On a side note, if you need to pass any parameters at the same time, then the simplest way to do this is with Python's anonymous function `lambda`. This can be accomplished like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def login(variable):
    print("Login triggered")

login_button = Button(root, text="Login", command=lambda: login("variable"))
login_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I used the "command" attribute as well and got the same result. I'll take a look at that second approach using lambda, never saw that.

Comment: @JoãoFróis The bottom two sections are more for fixing problems you'll likely have later. I've explained why it always returns true at the top of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I never used tkinter but I guess it's because you're calling the `get` method while your initialising the gui. (`name = input_name.get()`)
Instead you should only call this when the user clicks the button, which is inside the `login` method.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

label_name = Label(root, text="Username", fg="black")
label_password = Label(root, text="Password", fg="black")
input_name = Entry(root)
input_password = Entry(root, show="*")

label_name.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E)
label_password.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E)

input_name.grid(row=0, column=1)
input_password.grid(row=1, column=1)

checkbox = Checkbutton(root, text="Remember me")
checkbox.grid(columnspan=2, sticky=W)

login_button = Button(root, text="Login")
login_button.grid(row=1, column=2)


login_success = Label(root, text="Welcome", fg="black")
login_fail = Label(root, text="login fail", fg="black")


def login(event):
    name = input_name.get()
    password = input_password.get()
    if name == password:
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.grid_forget()
        login_true = Label(root, text="Welcome", fg="black")
        login_true.grid()
    elif name != password:
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.grid_forget()
        login_false = Label(root, text="login fail", fg="black")
        login_false.grid()


login_button.bind("<Button-1>", login)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried it as well, the same result, no matter what the input is I get the "welcome" text!

Comment: It is working now! I am stupid I was clicking login without writing anything on the boxes assuming that it would fail since i wrote nothing. Thanks for the reply.